# Is there a COM type library for Windows Core Audio

Tags: c#, audio, com, com-interop

I am trying to call Windows Core Audio from C#. I understand I can use NAudio and NetCoreAudio.

However I wanted to get or generate a type library for the Windows Core Audio libraries AudioSes.dll and MMDeviceApi.dll and import it into my project

I have tried Tlbexp, TlbImp and RegAsm. The dlls do not seem to contain the type information. If it is not in theses dlls where can I find it.

Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no type library to hold information about MMDevice API interfaces. Native code apps use Windows SDK headers which define these interfaces, and C# apps will have to have their own private code definitions, such as those in NAudio source, [IAudioClient.cs](http://daisy-svn.cvsdude.com/urakawa-sdk/trunk/csharp/audio/NAudio/CoreAudioApi/Interfaces/IAudioClient.cs):

```
namespace NAudio.CoreAudioApi.Interfaces
{
    /// <summary>
    /// n.b. WORK IN PROGRESS - this code will probably do nothing but crash at the moment
    /// Defined in AudioClient.h
    /// </summary>
    [Guid("1CB9AD4C-DBFA-4c32-B178-C2F568A703B2"), 
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioClient
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int Initialize(AudioClientShareMode shareMode,
            AudioClientStreamFlags StreamFlags,
            long hnsBufferDuration, // REFERENCE_TIME
            long hnsPeriodicity, // REFERENCE_TIME
            [In] WaveFormat pFormat,
            [In] ref Guid AudioSessionGuid);
```